# How to split a string on | (pipe) in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string like `|serialNo|checkDelta?|checkFuture?|checkThis?|`.

Now I am using the following code to split the string.

`String[] splitString = str.split("|");`

but when I use this I get array of string that contains each and every character, whereas I need string which contains letter like `serialNo`, `checkDelta?`, `checkFuture?`, `checkthis?`.

How to get these? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to escape your pipe character ([split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as argument and therefore "|" is a [control character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)):

```
str.split("\\|");
```

Please note: the resulting array contains an empty string at the beginning since you have "|" at start of your string.

Comment: +1 for the note good thing to metion

Comment: An alternative syntax for an equivalent regular expression is: `"[|]"` -- the pipe loses it's meaning in a character class.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a special character and will have to escape it: `str.split("\\|");`

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer..

```
String str="|serialNo|checkDelta?|checkFuture?|checkThis?|"
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str,"|",false);
String s1 = st.nextToken();
String s2 = st.nextToken();
String s3 = st.nextToken();
String s4 = st.nextToken();
```

s1=serialNo

s2=checkDelta?

s3=checkFuture?

s4=checkThis?

Refer to javadocs for reading about StringTokenizer

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html