# JAVA string split with regex ("||") cannot be used?

Tags: java, regex, split

It's my first time to use the .split() method in JAVA to split string. Unfortunately,what I've been given is to put "||" as the split regex. But it didn't work. Does anyone know why?
.split() works just fine when I use "//" or "/" or "--". I'm just curious why "||" provides different result.

Simulation:

```
String a = abc||acs||bbb

a.split("||") will provide the following result:
a
b
c
|
|
a
c
s
|
|
b
b
b
-END OF RESULT-
```

Does anyone out here knows why? It works just fine with "//" or anything else but not "||". Thanks!

SORRY! THE ANSWER IS [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682724/how-to-split-a-string-on-pipe-in-java)